# How to model data that is repeated over time within the same group, from which outcome variable is categorical and explanatory variables are linked?

Tags: statistics, regression, model

I have 1 dependent variable that is categorical. And I have 3 explanatory variables, the two continuous variables are likely interrelated and the 1 categorical variable is not interlinked.
The sample group has been measured at two different times and has mostly similar participants.
Now I want to find out how a change in dependent variable can be explained by changes in explanatory variables.
What is the best statistical model to use?

I would like to make a graph out of it, in which the y-axis = categorical outcome, x-axis = percentual change of explanatory variables (-100% till 100%) and the lines are based on two dots from the average explanatory variables per year. I was thinking about using a GEE model. Would this be a good model?

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp. Before diving to deep into which model is appropriate, I would always first simply create some 2D Scatter plots to get a feel for the data. You already seem to have suspicions about how the data may be interellated. Appropriate libraries could be pyplot/matplotlib or even gnuplot.

Comment: You might also consider posting or migrating to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Before cross-posting or migrating, I'd look for similar Questions at another SE Community.  I'm not familiar with Data Science, but [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) has thousands of posts that mention "explanatory variables" and models.